# how to increase height of top form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

See my screen shot to found that what is I want.
I want increase top of my form in windows 7:

[image]

Comment: No, see red arrows in screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot does not show exactly what you want. Are you trying to move the form up, or move a control inside the form to the top of the form?

If it is a control inside the form then here is a way:

let's assume the control you want to move up is a frame named Frame1

```
Me.Frame1.Top = 0   'This will move the whole frame to the very top of the form
```

If you want the form to move up the screen, then:

```
Me.Top = 0
```

Comment: see red arrows in screenshot, i want increase height of titleBar Or Top of dialog

Comment: This seems like something that you can accomplish using the Form Designer. Are you sure you want to change the form layout during runtime?

Comment: I think should be done with `http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack` but i can use it, i want when program runed form style look like to my screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Resource: http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm

Comment: i want just increase height of titleBar or top of form

Comment: @Davood check out the project it should contain some ways to increase your titlebar with 1 height.

Comment: of course, but i think this feature only exists in windows 7 and vista